# A problem regarding tensors

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

If $T_i$ are the components of a covariant vector, show that $\left(\frac{\partial T_i}{\partial x^j}-\frac{\partial T_j}{\partial x^i}\right)$ are the components of a skew-symmetric tensor of rank 2.

My plan was to prove that $\left(\frac{\partial T_i}{\partial x^j}-\frac{\partial T_j}{\partial x^i}\right)$ are the components of a covariant tensor of rank 2 in step 1 and then showing that it is skew-symmetric in step 2.

So how to prove the above the statements of the two steps above?

Comment: Even easier: If you define the $1$-form $\omega = \sum T_i dx^i$, then $d\omega = \sum\limits_{j<i} \left(\frac{\partial T_i}{\partial x^j}-\frac{\partial T_j}{\partial x^i}\right)dx^j\wedge dx^i$.